# How to set custom headers for the `HyperlinkButton` control?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to set custom headers for the `HyperlinkButton` control? I can specify the URL by setting the `NavigateUri` property (for example `HyperlinkButton.NavigateUri="http://www.example.com"`), but I can't see any way to set headers like, for example:

```
X-ApiAuth-Username: username
X-ApiAuth-Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2015 10:48:42 GMT
Authorization: ApiAuth CLcQbLlK3HajC/PPpwwxLoqHCnCrlM1VBjN8TGnYjuM=
```

My goal is to share the authorization token between my Windows Phone app and the third-party website.

I am aware that I can use the `WebView` control (and the `NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(...)` method), but I prefer to use the default browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to open the external browser with any headers. You have to use a WebView in your app.